# Google Assistant training shows slots with "meta" types but data received is not valid

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I am trying to train my agent and it recognizes all the slots I added, but it is recognizing them as having entity types like "meta.any" or "meta.number" instead of "sys.number". On my webhook, I get the slots filled incorrectly. I don't see where the "meta" slot type is documented.

What is the "meta" slot?

[image]

Comment: I ended up with something similar today - I was working on an agent on Friday, and added three sys.any parameters. Now I come back to it and it has duplicated all three parameters as meta.any and is complaining that they must be unique within the action.

Comment: I've just been changing them to their "sys." counterpart on training. Maybe that's how training works? I wish it was documented somewhere...

Comment: I submitted a support ticket, and the response was "Our engineers are working on this issue and we will update you once the issue is fixed." So it's definitely not working as designed, I guess.